# JAR does not recognize referenced libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries, noclassdeffounderror

When I launch jar file from terminal it gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError as obviously it cannot recognize referenced libraries that I have included in the project.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/icepdf/core/exceptions/PDFException
```

However I have added them to build path.

I am using the following command to launch my application:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you added your core project in the Deployement assembly ?

Comment: Have you setted the libraries inside jar file after building It as a runnable jar file?

Comment: Nope I am not sure I know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you have your core project in the workspace:

- Right click on the project that will use the core project in `Eclipse`
- Go to `properties`
- Then "`Deployment Assembly`" on the left
- Use the button `Add` on the right
- Choose `project` and search your core project and use the "`Finish`" button
- Built your project